# Reverse Pascal loop like in VB

Tags: loops, pascal

I have a 'For' loop that displays pages in a Wizard.

The loop looks like this:

```
  for i := 0 to nodes.Length - 1 do 

  begin

  end;
```

How to reverse it to display last items first? In VB, I would add a `Step -1` to the loop to start with the last item. How to accomplish the same behavior in Pascal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i := nodes.Length - 1 downto 0 do 
  begin

  end;
```

Comment: +1. Just as a note: You can also use `Pred(nodes.Length)` instead of `nodes.Length - 1`.

Comment: @Ken, except that 95% of programmers don't know what pred(x) means, which does not make for readable code.

Comment: For non-integers, pred would be needed, but nodes.Length is an integer, and nodes.Length - 1 is clearer.